# Is Blazor AuthenticationState safe?

Tags: authentication, blazor

Well, I created a Blazor app with Visual Studio then used

`@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider` and

```
    @code 
    {
        var authstate = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var s = await Service.GetSensitiveInfo(authstate);
    }
```

on a .razor page. In the Service I get the userId(Microsoft UserId) from authstate and use that as a key to get sensitive info from database. Is this safe? Can the user temper with the authstate and send a different userId.

P.S.  I also want to know what would be the best practice for these kind of situations.

Thank you for your time. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: They could so you should always check the identity at the server/api etc and not rely on sent credentials. Identity in the client should only be used to control the visibility of UI elements and not trusted. If this is server-side Blazor the argument is moot as this is not exposed to the client.

Comment: [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#authentication)